# Can not change the data type with NULL(DATE) in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR2VQ.png)I just cannot resolve this task. I have column which contains NULLs and DATE, but the type of column is nvarchar(50). When I execute the code I get column termdate just with NULLs, how can I avoid this result?

```sql
UPDATE projects.dbo.hr
set termdate = try_convert(date, termdate),
where try_convert(date, termdate) is not null
ALTER TABLE projects.dbo.hr
ALTER COLUMN termdate date
```

I don't understand how I can use this sample to avoid NULLs

```
SET termdate = ISNULL(NULLIF(termdate, ''), NULL)
```

Comment: It looks like maybe you are trying to change your table to use a date instead of nvarchar? That is excellent. Maybe you should change your update around a little bit and drop the where clause. That way any value that can't be converted to a date will be NULL which is what you want I would think.

Comment: I just can't figure out the last part of what you are trying to do. The NULL part is confusing. If you don't have a valid date then NULL would be appropriate.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will likely help us help you here. The `WHERE` in the above makes little sense, as this means that for any rows that couldn't be converted the data will be left as it was and so your `ALTER TABLE` statement will then error.

Comment: I have column with data type nvarchar(50) but it contains date and NULLs, so I try to change column type from nvarchar(50) to date. But after executing the code above I get new updated column which contains just NULLs. All my data in that column update to NULL instead of changing just data type.